# Invalid characters replace using VIM

Tags: text-processing, vim, google-drive

In my file due to some reasons some invalid characters are coming making it very huge file. Sample below of one line. I am not sure where these characters are coming from(I am using google drive online text editor). Please help me to find and replace and all and to avoid getting such characters?

It is a file name of a zip file, however not sure how those weird characters came.

This is a screenshot of a text file (containing the filenames of a directory). The filenames were obtained by running `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/\.\///g'`. I then saved this text file in google drive. When I open the file, I can see these characters:

looks like â€™ characters are converted to ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ

[image]

Comment: So it's a Zip archive that is called `telegramfiles.txt`, and you have opened it in Vim? Why don't you just rename it `telegramfiles.zip` and unzip it? (if it even needs renaming)

Comment: nope. It is a text file containing many filenames

Comment: Its not clear from the question, but are you saying this is a valid text document in Google Docs?  If so, how did you save it? It's fairly straight forward to save a document in any format from Google Docs.

Comment: it is a screenshot of a text file(containing the filenames of a directory). The filenames are got by running find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/\.\///g' command. then i save this text file in google drive. if i reopen the file these characters are showing up

Comment: character â€™ may be converted to ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ I think

Comment: if you see `â€™` then the encodings are incorrect. That's an apostrophe in UTF-8. The input is in UTF-8 but you're opening the file as ISO-8859-1